# Working on live site with local CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all, moderators, if i am posting this in wrong section, i apologize, and if you need to delete it, no problems.

I am working on a complex (very complex) live site for which i need to code a responsive layout.I cant clone the site locally since it is too big and i dont have an access to everything, so only thing left is to work on it live.

Is there any way (browser addon, separate program), which would allow me to load CSS stylesheet stored on my computer each time i visit the site so i can test it "in action"?

Dunno did i explained it properly, but if anybody knows any solution, i would be more than happy to hear it :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could make it so that one style sheet is shown to your ip address and one to everyone else.

```
<?php $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if ($ip == YOUR IP) : ?>
    Link to new stylesheet
<?php endif; ?>
```

( If you don't have access to do this, Greasemonkey may also work - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ )

Comment: Clever, but it'll make things a bit tricky if he is not always working from the same IP - or even more so if more people are working from a shared IP and the others need to se the unmodified site. But if that's not the case, this is probably the solution I would go with.

Comment: great solution! Like @funkylaundry said, depends if it applies to the OP's specific needs, but either way, good one to have in back pocket

Comment: @Richard B greasemonkey is works only for js? How can i use other filetypes?

Comment: @Husen You'd write a javascript to swap out the html css link on the page load, so that it points to your css instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always just save it on your HDD (Ctrl + s) and then work on static version from your hard drive.

Comment: True, but the site updates often so i always have to have the latest version so this really isnt an options :(

Comment: You can try to use this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha but its dedicated to Chrome

Answer (score 0):

If, on the live site, the stylesheets are coming from a dedicated domain or a dedicated sub-domain, you can edit your `hosts` file to make your browser look those files up from a local webserver instead.

For example, if you have the following set-up on the live site:

- `www.example.com` is the main application/site
- `static.example.com` is where static files are coming from

then you can add the following to `/etc/hosts` (on Linux, *BSD or OSX), or `\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` (on Windows):

```
127.0.0.1    static.example.com
```

Now all requests for static content are coming to your local system. You can then use a local webserver like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80` or (the much faster) https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server to serve those requests from a local folder.

Note that this won't work for SSL/TLS sites (ie `https`).

Answer (score 0):

You could put the .css file in your dropbox public folder (if your version of Dropbox is post-2012 you need to enable public folder manually: https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public) and reference the permanent link in your `<head>` - i.e.

```
<head>...
<link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/838533/livesites/bootstrap-force-device/css/force-device.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

...I am using PSPad. You can get it for free here:

http://www.pspad.com/

...with it you can connect to your ftp and alter your files online.

For quick tests I would suggest using the Firefox element inspector. Just change the code to see the results and then alter the actual live site.